# How to send multipart/form-data request using Postman

Tags: multipartform-data

I am currently using the Chrome Addon Postman - REST Client to easily create POST / GET request.

Now I want to debug an upload script and I am **looking for a way to make requests encoded as "multipart/form-data"** so that I can send also a file.

Answer (score 1893, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I have created a [video on sending multipart/form-data requests](https://youtu.be/c07IsbSNqfI) to explain this better.

---

Actually, [Postman](https://www.postman.com) can do this.

[image]

Full example:

[image]

You DON'T need to add any headers, Postman will do this for you automatically.

[image]

Make sure you check the comment from @maxkoryukov

> Be careful with explicit Content-Type header. Better - do not set it's
> value, the Postman is smart enough to fill this header for you. BUT,
> if you want to set the Content-Type: multipart/form-data - do not
> forget about [boundary field](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20321259/1115187).

Comment: postman's form-data params sometimes doesn't get into my Laravel API's REST methods.  Not sure why.

Comment: @Valentin, I tried this with the localhost on Google App Engine (Python 2.7), but it threw a internal server error (500). Is there something else you had to do to get it to work?

Comment: Google App Engine gave the internal server error?

Comment: @YonatanNir You must select POST, instead of the pre-selected GET method.

Comment: I did. When selecting POST it added an option to send a header and body. The body has 3 tabs: Raw, Form, Files. In the form tab you can add key-values for parameters but the files are in a separate tab and there is no option to allocate them to a parameter.

Comment: @YonatanNir I have added a newer screenshot with a recent Postman version. Hope this helps.

Comment: Error `"There is no multipart/form-data content in request"`

Comment: It isn't working with PUT request

Comment: Be careful with explicit **`Content-Type`** header. Better - do not set it's value, the Postman is smart enough to fill this header for you. **BUT**, if you want to set the `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` - do not forget about **boudary** field.

Comment: @maxkoryukov Thank your for your comments. My API was not working at all while I was trying multipart file upload using Postman client. Suddenly I came across your comments and this literally save my ass :). But, could you explain more on the `boundary` field. I know that postman adds boundary on its own. How do I do it manually?  :)

Comment: @oathkeeper, here is a good enough explanation of **boundary**: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20321259/1115187 In two words: you could set *boundary* manually and there are couple of simple rules.

Comment: In my case, I have to change "fileName" to "file" for my Ruby on Rails server.

Comment: Really Helpful.

Comment: Remember that you have to explicitly type a key name. E.g. "file". Otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Perhaps you's remind user to remove "Content-Type" header explicitly. Otherwise I get this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415084/multipart-data-post-using-python-requests-no-multipart-boundary-was-found

Comment: heads up that in Postman 7.1.0, I had to manually enter text in the "Key" column, as leaving it blank kept giving me an error.

Comment: Did you really upload a 28 min video for this?

Comment: Useful info, thanks... Sometimes we have to set it manually..  In my case I have to change from text to json

Comment: @ValentinDespa, what if we want to send image and a text simultaneously? What do we do then.

Comment: @SunilShah add another key with the next and set the proper content type

Comment: for Uvicorn, you need to specify the `Key` and not simply put anything.

Answer (score 253):

The usual error is one tries to put `Content-Type: {multipart/form-data}` into the header of the post request. That will fail, it is best to let Postman do it for you. For example:

**Suggestion To Load Via Postman**
[image: Body Part]

**Fails If In Header**
[image: Common Error]

**Works**
[image: should remove content type from the Header]

Comment: Nice tip about leaving out the "Content-Type" header!

Comment: Removing Content-Type fixed my issue with exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException: Missing start boundary  THANK YOU

Comment: be sure to set the key that you have set in your multer configuration

Comment: Not removing the default header will cause all sorts of issues.

Comment: Why does removing the Content-Type work? Isn't there a way to do it manually?

Comment: Auto population of Content-Type header ate my day. Thanks for the tip to remove it!

Comment: For me does not work

Comment: @Hung removing header solved my problem

Comment: How can I access the request body in the server? like to console.log() the values passed. When I do req.body.value its undefined

Comment: I am getting the multipart file as null in my java code. What I am missing ? any suggestion ?