# Handle Request with multipart data in API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, rest, multipart

I have an API (Asp.Net, written in C#) which receive a POST request on it, the request is multipart/form-data. My code to handle the request is the following:

```
if (request.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType.ToString() == "multipart/form-data")
{
    var providerMulti = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
    providerMulti.Wait();
    var result = providerMulti.Result;
}
```

As the `Wait()` is called, I receive this Exception:

> Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided. It does not have a
>   'multipart' content-type header with a 'boundary'
>   parameter.\r\nParameter name: content

I don't understand.

Comment: This is really late, but for the benefit people seeking answers, "The multipart content types needs to be specified with a boundary value as well", but here based on your if condition it looks like a custom constructed content type. Here is a sample content type constructed by Postman `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryQSVEr5LUBQLvkqQg`. Notice the `boundary` attribute here. That is what ASP is complaining about.

Comment: I got the hint from this page,http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2

Comment: Related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24503961/465053) with exactly same error text.

Comment: Are you using POSTMAN tool (a Google Chrome extension/app) at client side to sent POST requests? If you are using postman client tool to send request to your service then explicitly setting `content-type` to `multipart/form-data` is what messes up the request. Just avoid setting content-type explicitly as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43868741/465053). Just let me know if this solved your then I'll convert my comment in to an answer.