# Sails.js : File upload not working

Tags: node.js, api, sails.js, image-uploading

I am developing a REST API in [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/#!/). I am trying to create an API which uploads images on to the server. This API is going to be called by my mobile device. My upload API is as follows.

```
upload: function (req, res) {

    res.setTimeout(0);

    req.file('avatar')
    .upload({

      // You can apply a file upload limit (in bytes)
      maxBytes: 1000000

    }, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
      if (err) return res.serverError(err);
      else return res.json({
        files: uploadedFiles,
        textParams: req.params.all()
      });
    });
}
```

I use [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) to test my APIs. I call the API as follows

[image: POSTMAN]

My response says that there aren't any files uploaded. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: When you upload a file, the whole file is sent, not just the file name. I'm not sure if there is a way to do it or not in DHC, but you can in Postman. See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request

Comment: btw, why is your title "Install Node.js 0.10.36 on Amazon Linux"? That doesn't seem related to your question.

Comment: Paulpro, I've tried the same with POSTMAN. The results are still the same. Please find the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of investigation I found that the problem was with [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) and not with [sails](http://sailsjs.org/#!/)'s [skipper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/skipper). I used [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue and even used Advance REST client as suggested above. But after researching and almost submitting an issue in [POSTMAN](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues). My issue was that I was adding the custom header `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` AND selecting form-data it was interfering with the correct headers.  If you select form-data, there is no need to set the custom header.

Comment: This must be the selected answer. Remove headers and this will work just as said