# Django REST Framework file upload

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to upload file with some form data. For testing my api I am using Postman.When I try to POST with file and other fields, I got this error

```
{
  "detail": "JSON parse error - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 10: invalid start byte"
}
```

Here is my model:

```
class Music(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks')
    playlist = models.ForeignKey(Playlist, null=True, related_name='tracks')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    dropbox_id = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

serializer:

```
class MusicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    file = serializers.FileField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Music
        fields = ('id', 'favorite', 'created_at', 'counter', 'file', 'name', 'album', 'playlist')
```

and view :

```
class MusicViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Music.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MusicSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        file_obj = self.request.FILES['file']
        dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(JSON_DATA['dropbox_access_token'])
        res = dbx.files_upload(file_obj, '/', autorename=True, mute=True)
        print(res)
        serializer.save(dropbox_id='x')
```

Comment: Have you set "content-type: application/json" in HEADER?

Comment: Yes of course. There are three headers : Authorization, Accept and Content-Type

Comment: Content-type is not needed. Remove it and then check.

Comment: Can you show the request? I suspect that you can not upload the file the way you are trying to... Also as a starting point look at this: https://gist.github.com/yprez/7704036

Comment: Json cannot be used to send direct files, you should send data with `multipart/form-data` content type instead. Also, you would need to specify a `MultiPartParser` in `parser_classes` in your `ViewSet` then if its not specified in the settings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You cannot upload files with `JSON` request content**.

You should instead send data with `multipart/form-data` content. DRF's [`MultiPartParser`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser) handles multipart HTML form content which supports file uploads.

> [**`MultiPartParser`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser)
>   Parses `multipart` HTML form content, which supports
>   file uploads. Both `request.data` will be populated with a `QueryDict`.
>
> You will typically want to use both `FormParser` and `MultiPartParser`
>   together in order to fully support HTML form data.

In your `MusicViewSet`, you can define `FormParser` and `MultiPartParser`, if they are not defined in your settings so that DRF can parse the multipart HTML form content. You can access the `file` using `serializer.validated_data` in `perform_create()` method.

```
class MusicViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Music.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MusicSerializer
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser) # set parsers if not set in settings. Edited

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        file_obj = serializer.validated_data['file'] # access file
        dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(JSON_DATA['dropbox_access_token'])
        res = dbx.files_upload(file_obj, '/', autorename=True, mute=True)
        serializer.save(dropbox_id='x')
```

Comment: Now I got this error `{
  "detail": "Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None"
}`

Comment: @pyprism What is the `content-type` header you are sending?

Comment: multipart/form-data

Comment: Using postman, you just need to select 'form data' option without adding content-type header. There you should  add the file along with other keys.

Comment: Also check this link for file upload using Postman. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request

Comment: Did you try with the method posted in the above link?