# Uploading File using Advanced Rest Client Google Chrome Api

Tags: rest, http, upload, client

I'm trying to work with the Advanced REST Client. I have configured the settings as follows.

http://postimg.org/image/bmfeus19l/

As you may see in the Image it creates the file in the container as desired. However the file when Opened contains the original text and some foreign text as show below.

```
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryQLJKBuyuxTtZiQkA
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="note1s"; filename="note1.txt"
    Content-Type: text/plain

    THIS IS A TEST FILE AND WILL BE UPLOADED...
    THIS IS A TEST FILE AND WILL BE UPLOADED...

    THIS IS A TEST FILE AND WILL BE UPLOADED...
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryQLJKBuyuxTtZiQkA--
```

Please help me, as I am new to using this tool. I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I've **faced the same problem** and opened an **[Issue](https://github.com/jarrodek/ChromeRestClient/issues/981)**.

**This is not the answer but** I guess you should **consider  using PostMan**. I've tried this one and works fine...

**Check it out how to: [Tool for sending multipart/form-data request [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request)**