# Including JSON as part of an HttpPost that has attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, http

I'm accepting a file with my controller:

```
[HttpPost, Route("api/upload")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Upload()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType); 

    var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
    foreach (var file in provider.Contents)
    {
        var filename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
        var buffer = await file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        //Do whatever you want with filename and its binaray data.
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

**How do I allow the client to also be able to post json in the body of the request?**

Comment: use `[FromBody]` to accept the request from body

Comment: unable to test with postman, any examples how to test this?

Answer (score 1):

```
 [Route("{lang}/documents")]
    public async Task PostDocument()
    {
        string dirPath = _appConfigurationManager.GetDocumentFolder();
        if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))
        {
            DirectoryInfo createdir = Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
        }

        if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            if (Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString().IndexOf("filename=\"\"") == -1)
            {
                var streamProvider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(dirPath);
                var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
                var fileEntity = new ViewModels.Common.FileDescViewModel();

                foreach (var file in result.FileData)
                {
                    fileEntity.FileName = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
                    fileEntity.Url = "~/" + fileEntity.FileName;                       
                }

                var jsonmodel = result.FormData["jsonData"].ToString().Replace("\"content\":\"\",", string.Empty);
                if (jsonmodel == null)
                    throw new Exception();

                var siteViewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocumentViewModel>(jsonmodel);
                siteViewModel.Url = fileEntity.Url;                   
                siteViewModel.Name = fileEntity.FileName;
                AddDocumentDetails(siteViewModel);
            }
            else
            {
                string jsonData = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Replace("\"content\":\"\",", string.Empty);
                jsonData = jsonData.Substring(jsonData.IndexOf('{'), jsonData.LastIndexOf('}') - jsonData.IndexOf('{') + 1);
                var siteViewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocumentViewModel>(jsonData);
                AddDocumentDetails(siteViewModel);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my actual test code. try it It will definitely run.

Comment: thank you very much i am unable to mark this up because my reputation doesnt allow it, but i will try it!! why do you define this as a Task? why  not a regular method?

Comment: also could you suggest how to configure postman to test this?

Comment: I want process my AddDocument part as asynchronous that is why I used Task.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request