# How to Postman POST json body and attach file?

Tags: java, postman

I have back-end API to allow user **POST** a `json_body` and with a file:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendemail",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
            consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}
)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> sendEmailToClients(
       @RequestBody String jsonData,
       @RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) final MultipartFile file) {
        ...
}
```

**Question:** On **Postman Tool**, Is there any way to make a `POST` for sending out `json_body` and file upload?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tool for sending multipart/form-data request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request)

Comment: No, I mean I want to send a POST for both json body and file. 

I know that I can send a file and add some url's parameters. Or I can send a json body with some url's parameters.

Comment: This is unclear, update your question please

Comment: I've updated the question. Pls help, thanks!