# Error "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null" in laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, postman, intervention

I am using intervention for image upload functionality but when I am trying to upload image from postman with "content-type: multipart/form-data" in header, it shows up above error, but if I remove content-type header then it is working fine. I have added images of postman .                          [image: Postman header with request]
[image: **Postman image upload**]

**my route**

> Route::post('contact/image/upload',['as'=>'intervention.postresizeimage','uses'=>'contactController@upload_image']);

**code in controller**

```
public function upload_image(Request $request){

      if((preg_match("/^[789]\d{9}$/", $request->header('UID')))){

        $photo = $request->file('image');
        $imagename = time().'.'.$photo->getClientOriginalExtension(); 

        $destinationPath_thumb = storage_path('images/thumbnail_images');
        $thumb_img = Image::make($photo->getRealPath())->resize(100, 100);
        $thumb_img->save($destinationPath_thumb.'/'.$imagename,80);

        $destinationPath_medium = storage_path('images/medium_images');
        $medium_img = Image::make($photo->getRealPath())->resize(500, 500);
        $medium_img->save($destinationPath_medium.'/'.$imagename,80);

        $destinationPath_original = storage_path('images/original_images');
        $photo->move($destinationPath_original, $imagename);

        $user = \App\User::select(['inst_id'])->where('mobile','=',$request->header('UID'))->first();

        $update_img = \App\Contact::where([['id','=',$request->ID],['inst_id','=',$user->inst_id]])->update(['image'=>$imagename]);

        if($update_img)
          $response = response()->json(['data'=>[], 'error'=>0,  'error_msg'=>'', 'message'=>'Profile updated']);
        else
          $response = response()->json(['data'=>[], 'error'=>1,  'error_msg'=>'some went wrong', 'message'=>'Please try again']);
      }
      else
         $response = response()->json(['data'=>[], 'error'=>1,  'error_msg'=>'wrong mobile in UID header','message'=>'wrong mobile no. in header']);

    return  $response;

  }
```

Comment: Your photo has not uploaded. try using this $photo[0] in place of photo

Comment: Where should I change this ?

Comment: Try printing $photo variable and check the value. Also check your form it should be enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: @shafiq  I am using laravel as a API so how do i check this enctype ?

Comment: I have tried to print $photo using dd($photo) so I got empty array in response.

Comment: @SaMeEr
$photo should give you Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile Object. Its means file is not uploading. 
Check your content type.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request#answer-41435972

Comment: @SaMeEr 
I think you are including content-type in your request.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request#answer-41435972

Comment: @shafiq . yes I am. but I think it should be added there because android and ios devices are requesting with this header which is not working.

Comment: @SaMeEr Android and ios should send request with content-type:multipart/form-data however in postman you don't add it as postman already including it.
For android and iso it will work only when content-type:multipart/form-data is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> File is missing in your input so it is becoming null, so it is advised
>   to check if there is file on input request and continue else return
>   error.

And also in you `HTML` form add this

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

or if you are using laravel collective then add `'files'=> true` in Form

and I have updated your code to do the checking if file is present at below

```
public function upload_image(Request $request){

  if((preg_match("/^[789]\d{9}$/", $request->header('UID')))){

    if(!$request->hasFile('image')) {

      return response()->json(['data'=>[], 'error'=>1,  'error_msg'=>'image file is required', 'message'=>'image file is required for upload']);
    }

    $photo = $request->file('image');
    $imagename = time().'.'.$photo->getClientOriginalExtension(); 

    $destinationPath_thumb = storage_path('images/thumbnail_images');
    $thumb_img = Image::make($photo->getRealPath())->resize(100, 100);
    $thumb_img->save($destinationPath_thumb.'/'.$imagename,80);

    $destinationPath_medium = storage_path('images/medium_images');
    $medium_img = Image::make($photo->getRealPath())->resize(500, 500);
    $medium_img->save($destinationPath_medium.'/'.$imagename,80);

    $destinationPath_original = storage_path('images/original_images');
    $photo->move($destinationPath_original, $imagename);

    $user = \App\User::select(['inst_id'])->where('mobile','=',$request->header('UID'))->first();

    $update_img = \App\Contact::where([['id','=',$request->ID],['inst_id','=',$user->inst_id]])->update(['image'=>$imagename]);

    if($update_img)
      $response = response()->json(['data'=>[], 'error'=>0,  'error_msg'=>'', 'message'=>'Profile updated']);
    else
      $response = response()->json(['data'=>[], 'error'=>1,  'error_msg'=>'some went wrong', 'message'=>'Please try again']);
  }
  else
     $response = response()->json(['data'=>[], 'error'=>1,  'error_msg'=>'wrong mobile in UID header','message'=>'wrong mobile no. in header']);

return  $response;
```

}

Comment: Good. but what about android and ios devices which is requesting to my api and trying to upload the file . how do they change the request format?

Comment: Because they always set RequestHeader with content-type:multipart/form-data.

Comment: Actually the problem is not that. I am adding content-type header in postman so it is not working but if I remove this content-type header then it is working fine. But I am assuming that devices like android and ios are sending request with content-type: multipart/form-data so I should add this in postman . so that's why I am confused.