# How to send multipartFile and Json with postman and spring boot

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, postman

I want to send a file and a json model at one post request.

My Request Mapping looks like that:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/sftp/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<SftpModel> upload(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("sftpModel") SftpModel sftpModel) {
```

My Json has this structure:

```
{
  "sftpHost": "ftp01.Host.de",
  "sftpPort": 22,
  "sftpUser": "anyUser",
  "sftpPassword": "anyPass",
  "sftpRemoteDirectory": "/"
}
```

And the file is on my system.

I'm able to send the `file` or the `sftpModel` seperatly but not together. The error I receive is:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1497336812907,
  "status": 415,
  "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
  "message": "Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported",
  "path": "/secure-data-transfer-service/sftp/upload"
}
```

I tried it with postman and curl. But no chance.[image]

```
curl --form "file=@test.txt" --form "sftpModel={"sftpHost":"ftp01.Host.de","sftpPort":22,"sftpUser":"anyUser","sftpPassword":"anyPass","sftpRemoteDirectory":"/"}" http://localhost:8080/secure-data-transfer-service/sftp/upload
```

Is there any way to send both?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what is not working? Are you getting any specific error or anything else that you can share with us?

Comment: @ValentinDespa It's not much want I want to do. I just want to post a file and a json model with one request. The error I got is in my question. If I create a sftpModel.json file instead of write the model itself, it works

Comment: @Patrick were you able to find a solution for this? I am getting the same problem.

Comment: @NewQueries no. I just got it working by sending the file via multipart and the json as request parameter.

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16022213/355438

Answer (score 2):

You java code is looks like perfect.

`@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/sftp/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<SftpModel> upload(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("sftpModel") SftpModel sftpModel) { }`

You can write your SftpModel json string in one json file and try uploading with that json file.

[Click here to see the postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Opco.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(@RequestPart MultipartFile file, @RequestPart String user) {
            User users = new ObjectMapper().readValue(user, User.class);
}
```

Comment: Whats the difference between the code in the question and I dont even habe a user class...