# How to post file along with json data in Postman?

Tags: json, postman

I know how to post json and I know how to post file in multipart form in [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en). But how can I do both together. For example:

Here is my jason to post:

```
{
    "title": "Post title yeah",
    "body": "My first post body"

}
```

So how can I post `image.jpg` located at `/home/me/Desktop` along with the the above json?

**UPDATE:** Note that I want so send file **using JSON**, so my question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request) which is about multipart form sending using Postman.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tool for sending multipart/form-data request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request)

Comment: @BobSwager Here I want to send file exclusively along with JSON, so multipart form sending is irrelevant to my question.

Comment: @Karlom JSON doesn't support binary data, but if you're willing to convert the `Blob` to base64 encoding, which is 4/3 the size (8/3 in UTF-16, which JavaScript defaults to), I can answer that.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts please do answer. I absolutely need to transfer the file through json.

Comment: Wait, postman is a web interface? I thought you were using JavaScript or something... if using a web interface, you really should just use multipart/form-data or binary.

Comment: Right, postman is a chrome extentsion: https://www.getpostman.com/. You still can answer by mentioning why it is not possible and what is the alternative way? (i.e first encode, the use the encodes string at postman?)

Comment: @Karlom, did you find a solution? I have similar requirement. I want to send an image through json payload and receive it as a blob.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this online tool to convert your file to a base64 (https://www.browserling.com/tools/file-to-base64), then you can send it as part of the json. I reduced the size of the base64 string for the answer.

```
{
    "title": "Post title yeah",
    "body": "My first post body",
    "image": "JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMiAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggMjcyNS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGU+PnN0cmVhbQpYCb1c247byBF9X8D/0MC+JIFNs5t9IY0gwHicXRjI2GOPvPsQ5EGrocdKRGmiofby9+kmu5t901BFKoLhi8qqc04Xq07zZr/47r8olz84JlmORKV+3dfoZ7R9If8GcxVkeUZLjijNBEOYZhgT+523C/T6hwJVWVVVaPG1w5IID4gxluESLf6BMMuqkkqYImOMoMU9+tPH/X29R9+/+TNa/Bst/oL+vnjx3aeBkJcZqwQilfwwnU/gjFe843u3bOuYjHcLUstjVYlwgfX6cp+NJtgoI5no6RQKKSWMTGQ9HaG4EDzio2o9QshqckkjMklGMsJAbAqjIBKlyHJOO7acvCb8NcnlFzB7g+kbUqbrykUla0kR491CeVZFdcV4vLC8JFlJy477bre5R4v"
}
```

[image]