# Required request part is not present while uploading a file to Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload

I'm testing file upload both with Postman (knowing the [guides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request)) and Swagger UI. And Spring Boot complains as `Required request part 'file' is not present` although it's sent in fact, and it's presented in my Spring Boot app of course. The file is 80 KB.

Please help to get rid of that error.

Swagger log:

```
POST /some/url

Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,la;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:143168
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryBxCvTXJ7Xsst0oxO
Host:localhost:8080
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

------WebKitFormBoundaryBxCvTXJ7Xsst0oxO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="69426467.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
------WebKitFormBoundaryBxCvTXJ7Xsst0oxO--
```

Java controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some/url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String createPhoto(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipart) {
    ...
```

Comment: Which version of swagger ui did you used ?

Comment: I am using Swagger 2.6.1