# Swagger 2.0 File Upload type: file error

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, hapi.js, swagger-2.0

I want to upload image file.
Swagger 2.0 code for upload

```
/upload:
post:
   summary: Uploads a file.
   consumes:
     - multipart/form-data
   produces:
     - application/json
   parameters:
     - name: image
       in: formData
       required: false
       type: file
       description: The file to upload.
   responses:
      '200':
        description: OK (successfully uploaded)
      '500':
        description: Error importing file
```

I am testing this through postman were in body I have mentioned "form-data" 
key: "image" value :"Image file"

I am receiving following error

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "child \"image\" fails because [\"value\" must be a string]",
    "validation": {
        "source": "payload",
        "keys": [
            "image"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the Swagger spec correct, that is, does your server actually expect `multipart/form-data`? If this is correct, make sure you configured the request correctly in Postman - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16022213/113116).

Comment: thanks issue is resolved, just changed format to "binary" it was taking as string