# Unable to update a file in Postman using x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: python, postman

I need to update a file using Postman. In the Postman application, it doesn't show the option text or file. Is there any process to update a file using `x-www-form-urlencoded`, within Postman?

Comment: No. You can't. And why using postman?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request ? if it is the case, plz delete your question afterwards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tool for sending multipart/form-data request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request)