# File upload using postman

Tags: postman

Could you please tell me how to upload file without USING File option.
I would like to know how I can upload file by following below approach.

1. From Body - Form data - Type as Text approach
2. How I can upload file using Body - raw - Json file type

I do not want to use File > Choose File option. I would like to execute through newman and using File > Choose file option it is failing.

I tried to use below approach but it is giving 404 as response.

```
Body - Raw-->
{
"uploadType": "ORDER",
"headerIncluded":"false",
"file":"C:/Users/b3badm/Desktop/SIndoora/FileImport_ValidProducts.txt"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tool for sending multipart/form-data request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request)

Comment: The "choose file" option does exactly what you are asking for. It's juts a GUI option, but behind the curtains it uses your approach. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c07IsbSNqfI&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 5):

[image: img]

This option is hidden by default! Only move your cursor over the area will appear the *Text* for you to change to **File**! You should also put *file* or something in the key column.

Answer (score 0):

From the Postman GUI the only way to send a file is to add it as a form-data via *File -> Select Files* or *Binary -> Select files*.

If you want to execute such request via *Newman* you need to manually edit your collection.json file to add the full path to the file you're trying to send on your local machine in `request.body.formdata.src` parameter.

More details can be found in [Postman Blog](https://blog.getpostman.com/2017/09/21/run-collections-with-file-uploads-using-newman/).