# I want to call an API from another API and post file in that API as a form-data but file is not posting returning 204 No Content message, How to do?

Tags: c#, http, postman, form-data, restful-url

In attached image this is my code returning 204 no content message, I want success message 200 code but don't know how?

```
public HttpResponseMessage MakePostAsync()
{
    string apiUrl = "https://abc.c9api.in/api/method/upload_file";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, apiUrl);
    string filepath = @"C:\Users\Javed.shaikh\Desktop\CSVFiles\SalesOrderDetail.csv";
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Token f802cc75fabec4770:62fa1ba5aff78bbfc4d");
    content.Add(new StringContent("0"), "is_private");
    content.Add(new StringContent("Home"), "folder");
    var fileContent = new StreamContent(new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open));
    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
    {
        Name = "file",
        FileName = "SalesOrderDetail.csv"
    };
    content.Add(fileContent);
    request.Content = content;
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> result = client.SendAsync(request);
    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent("Response: ", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
    };
}
```

Comment: How do post files as a form-data like in postman to api call.

Comment: Why would you make an HTTP request and then create your own HTTP response in the client. That does not make any sense at all. You never use the response of your call in `result`? Also this question includes multiple questions. One about Postman and another about how to make an API call with form-data from C# therefore I am voting to close this question. You should focus on one thing. Both of which have been answered on SO already. E. g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715532/how-to-set-the-request-body-via-postmans-pre-request-script/73634536#73634536)

Comment: Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49795556/file-upload-using-postman) if you want to set the file manually.