# "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form." Error In RestFramework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am making a student admission system for that i need to upload image ,When iam uploading image  my models.py looks like this,

models.py:

```
def scramble_uploaded_filename(instance, filename):
    extension = filename.split(".")[-1]
    return "{}.{}".format(uuid.uuid4(), extension)

class StudentAdmission(BaseModel):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    admission_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    batch = models.IntegerField()
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField("Uploaded image", upload_to=scramble_uploaded_filename)
```

And im using a planeSerializer imageField in serializers.py like this:

serializers.py

```
class StudentAdmissionBaseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    user_detail = UserDetailSerializer()
    phone_detail = PhoneSerializer()
    address_detail = AddressSerializer()
    registration_no = serializers.IntegerField()
    batch = serializers.IntegerField()
    description = serializers.CharField(default='')
    image = serializers.ImageField()
```

And My views.py looks like this:

views.py:

```
class StudentAdmissionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = StudentAdmission.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentAdmissionSerializer
    parser_classes = (NestedMultipartParser,)



    def get(self, request):
        return Response([])
    def list(self, request):
        return Response([])

    def create(self,request):
        print({**request.POST,**request.FILES})
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data={**request.data,**request.FILES})


        if serializer.is_valid():
            data = serializer.data
            ud = data['user']

            user,b = User.objects.get_or_create(
                email=ud['email'],
                defaults={
                    'username':ud['email'],
                    'first_name':ud['first_name'],
                    'last_name':ud['last_name'],
                    'gender':ud['gender'],
                    'type':ud['type']
                    }
                )
            if not b:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({
                    'detail':["Email Already Exist"]
                    })



            c = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(user)
            Phone.objects.get_or_create(content_type=c,
                                        object_id=user.id,
                                        number=data['phone_detail']['number'],
                                        type=data['phone_detail']['type']
                                        )
            Address.objects.get_or_create(
                                        content_type=c,object_id=user.id,
                                        defaults={
                                        'province':data['address_detail']['province'],
                                        'district':data['address_detail']['district'],
                                        'city':data['address_detail']['city'],
                                        'address':data['address_detail']['address']
                                        }
                                        )

            detail = data.get('user_detail', False)
            if detail:
                UserDetail.objects.get_or_create(user_id=user.id,
                                                defaults={
                                                'blood_group':detail.get('blood_group',''),
                                                'nationality':detail.get('nationality',''),
                                                'mother_tongue':detail.get('mother_tongue',''),
                                                'religion':detail.get('religion',''),
                                                'citizenship_no':detail.get('citizenship_no',''),
                                                }
                                                )

            student,bval = Student.objects.get_or_create(user_id=user.id,registration_no=data['registration_no'])

            StudentAdmission.objects.get_or_create(student_id=student.id,
                                                   defaults={
                                                   'batch':data['batch'],
                                                   'course_id':data['course'],
                                                   'description':data['description'],
                                                   'image':data['image']
                                                   }
                                                   )

            return Response(data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({
                    'detail':serializer.errors
                    })
```

And here i have written a NestedMultipartParser .This is my Own parser class .The complete code of this parser class looks like This:

```
from rest_framework import parsers

class NestedMultipartParser(parsers.MultiPartParser):

    def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):

        result = super().parse(stream=stream, media_type=media_type, parser_context=parser_context)

        data = {}
        print(result.data)
        for key, value in result.data.items():
            if '.' in key:
                dict_key = key.split('.')
                nested_dict_key = dict_key[0]
                nested_value_key = dict_key[1]

                if nested_dict_key not in data:
                    data[nested_dict_key] = {}

                data[nested_dict_key][nested_value_key] = value 


                # if nested_value_key not in data:
                #   data[nested_dict_key] = {}
                #   data[nested_dict_key][nested_value_key] = value
                # else:
                #   data[key] = value
            else:
                data[key] = value
        return parsers.DataAndFiles(data,result.files)
```

This is the all of code that i have written, When i try to upload image through form then it raise the error like

"image": [
        "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
    ],

Can Anyone Explain  about This type of error?? and please Any developer can give me solution of it.Thank You!!!!

Comment: How are you passing data into API?

Comment: Using Django-Admin form

Comment: in your template in the form add enctype="multipart/form-data"  you need this for upload files in server.

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis I have Added This on header Section of Postman . Still Shows This same error

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request) this can help to test your api with postman

Comment: self.get_serializer(data={**request.data,**request.FILES}) looks highly suspicious. With Django REST framework, you should only use request.data which includes POST data and files as well.