# How to upload image to server using php laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, postman, image-uploading

I've  been trying to write an api to upload image to server ,but all in vain.
I'm using the laravel framework .And tried [this example](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-fileimage-upload-example-with-validationexample.html) but it is not working.

Also while testing the api from POSTMAN ,I have passed mutlipart/form-data in the Headers.And in the Body tab selected form-data, added key = image, changed it Text to File and added an image.But when I test the api , don't know why but the image request is empty.

Maybe I might be passing something wrong in POSTMAN or there might be something wrong in my code,please do help me.

Here's my api code

```
public function upload(Request $request){

if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
   $image = $request->file('image');
   $name = md5(time().uniqid()).".png";
   $destinationPath = base_path() . '/public/uploads/images/' . $name;

   move_uploaded_file($name, $destinationPath);

   return response()->json(['title'=>"image is uploaded"]);
   }

}
```

And my controller code :

```
Route::post('uploadImage','TestController@upload');
```

Screenshot of the postman request.Please tell me if I'm passing something wrong in header or body .

[image]

Also ,the console shows this error `Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of postman request?

Comment: You may refer this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user core PHP code for file upload.
In my laravel project I have used following code to upload file.

```
if(isset($_FILES["image"]["type"]))
{
  $FILES = $_FILES["image"];
  $upload_dir = storage_path('app/public/document/');

  // create folder if not exists
  if (!file_exists($upload_dir)) {
    mkdir($upload_dir, 0777, true);
  }

  //Send error 
  if ($FILES['error'])
  {
    return response()->json(['error'=>'Invalid file']);
  }

  //Change file name
  $target_file = md5(time().uniqid());
  $imageFileType = pathinfo($FILES["name"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $target_file = $upload_dir.$target_file.'.'.$imageFileType;

  //Upload file
  if (move_uploaded_file($FILES["tmp_name"], $target_file))
  {
    return response()->json(['success' => 'File uploading successful']);
  }
  else
  {
    return response()->json(['error'=>'Invalid file']);
  }
}else{
 return response()->json(['error'=>'Invalid file']);
}
```

Below is the screenshot when I print $_FILES at the beginning of the function
[image]

Comment: It shows "Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\TestController::$errorStatus" on the last line

Comment: In my API file I have added 
 "public $errorStatus = 500;" Please do not copy the code as it is. First understand then implement.

Comment: Maybe it's not getting the file and showing "invalid file" in response in the last else

Comment: you can check what is present in $_FILES by adding "print_r($_FILES);die;" before first if condition.

Comment: it is an empty array

Comment: Am I passing anything wrong in the header or body ,while testing the api in Postman? Please help

Comment: Please check the screenshot