# POSTMAN Request in form-data

Tags: java, spring-mvc, postman

[image]I have this method but I am not able to figure out which parameters should I pass in postman to execute this method. I sent the body in form-data of postman and content-Type is multipart/form-data.

Later I have to send the file as well that's why I am using form-data.

SearchString is coming out be empty in backend code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/calendar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected FareCalendarResponse getCalendar(
        @RequestParam(value = "searchString", required = false) String searchString, HttpServletRequest httpRequest)
        throws Exception {
    CalendarRequest fareRequest = new CalenderRequest(searchString);
    return FareCalendarHandler.builder().httpRequest(httpRequest).request(fareRequest).build().getResponse();
}
```

Comment: it's better to know what have you tried and what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think this link [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request) answers your question. 
Also, Because its a request Param, that will come as a query param / form data i think  from javadocs [RequestParam](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html)

your postman should look like :

[image]

And if you wish to upload file: 
[image]

Comment: Hey Raveesh Sharma, actually i have to send the file as well later

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be `public`
the content-type can be anything, try `application/json`
You can use postman to POST to `http://host:port/calendar?searchString=searchString`