# Java Spring : Upload multiple MultipartFile files along with JSON as a body into single request(HTTP->POST)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

*Hello Friends,*

I am looking for a solution where I can upload **multiple** *MultipartFile **along with** input JSON body*. I knew there are many related things available but none of the thing were I find my solution. which provoke me to ask a question to community.

> My requirement is something likewise,

I have developed(In fact developing & am in last stage) open source library where schools/colleges/universities would willingly upload study materials for students based upon subject wise. **Along** with material User(authenticated) must has to provide few text info like, *title, description, remarks*.

so My expected entity is something likewise,

```
@Entity
class Material {
private MultipartFile[] content;
private String title;
private String description;
private String remarks;
}
```

I would like to use spring MVC feature something likewise **where am getting failed & need** your help here,

```
public String uploadMaterial(@RequestBody Material material) {
... business logic ...
return "successfully material saved.";
}
```

*Any help will be really Appreciate!!*

Answer (score 4):

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Material createMaterial(@RequestPart("addtionalData") String addtionalData, @RequestPart("fileList") List<MultipartFile> fileList) throws IOException {

        Material material = new ObjectMapper().readValue(addtionalData, Material.class);
        material.setContent(fileList);
// do what ever you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement for one of my projects and i used below technique to upload the images

public Job uploadImageForAJo(@PathVariable Long jobId, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] files)

and here if you want you can pass a json payload with your other required information as the @RequestBody

you can have a look at below question to find how to test your api with postman

[Tool for sending multipart/form-data request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request)

Comment: this won't work in my case. because I neither pass title, desc in form of @ Pathvariable, nor form-data. As I said, my first choice would be @ RequestBody only. Thanks for your suggestion & highlight this point.

Comment: @vishalgajera may be you can convert images to base64 images and include as a json property

Answer (score 0):

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @PostMapping("/uploadDocuments")
    public Object uploadFilesOnAwsS3(
            @RequestHeader(name = "docId") String docId,
            @RequestHeader(name = "referenceId") String referenceId,
            @RequestHeader(name = "docTypeId") String docTypeId,
            @RequestParam(value = "data") Object data,
            @RequestParam(value = "files", required = true) MultipartFile[] files) throws IOException, MsuException {
    }