# Upload a file and also pass model data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

I need to import a file, and also the `Person` model that I have shown below.

I am able to upload the file, However, I am not able to retrieve the Person model data in the `importFileAndOtherInfo` method that I have written.

Note: I am testing this web API via Postman. How can I upload a file, and also send `Person` Model data via Postman?

Person

```
int pId
string PName
School schoolAttended
```

My implementation:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<int> importFileAndOtherInfo(Person person)
{

    var stream = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].InputStream

    // HOW TO RETRIEVE THE PERSON DATA HERE.

}
```

Comment: You can add files with postman last version here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/16022213/8265882

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is, you want to pass model data and the file in stream at the same time; you can't send it directly, the way around is to send file with `IFormFile` and add create your own model binder as follows,

```
public class JsonWithFilesFormDataModelBinder: IModelBinder
{
    private readonly IOptions<MvcJsonOptions> _jsonOptions;
    private readonly FormFileModelBinder _formFileModelBinder;

    public JsonWithFilesFormDataModelBinder(IOptions<MvcJsonOptions> jsonOptions, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _jsonOptions = jsonOptions;
        _formFileModelBinder = new FormFileModelBinder(loggerFactory);
    }

    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        // Retrieve the form part containing the JSON
        var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.FieldName);
        if (valueResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            // The JSON was not found
            var message = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ModelBindingMessageProvider.MissingBindRequiredValueAccessor(bindingContext.FieldName);
            bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, message);
            return;
        }

        var rawValue = valueResult.FirstValue;

        // Deserialize the JSON
        var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rawValue, bindingContext.ModelType, _jsonOptions.Value.SerializerSettings);

        // Now, bind each of the IFormFile properties from the other form parts
        foreach (var property in bindingContext.ModelMetadata.Properties)
        {
            if (property.ModelType != typeof(IFormFile))
                continue;

            var fieldName = property.BinderModelName ?? property.PropertyName;
            var modelName = fieldName;
            var propertyModel = property.PropertyGetter(bindingContext.Model);
            ModelBindingResult propertyResult;
            using (bindingContext.EnterNestedScope(property, fieldName, modelName, propertyModel))
            {
                await _formFileModelBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
                propertyResult = bindingContext.Result;
            }

            if (propertyResult.IsModelSet)
            {
                // The IFormFile was successfully bound, assign it to the corresponding property of the model
                property.PropertySetter(model, propertyResult.Model);
            }
            else if (property.IsBindingRequired)
            {
                var message = property.ModelBindingMessageProvider.MissingBindRequiredValueAccessor(fieldName);
                bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(modelName, message);
            }
        }

        // Set the successfully constructed model as the result of the model binding
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
    }
}
```

Model

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(JsonWithFilesFormDataModelBinder), Name = "data")]
public class Person
{
   public int pId {get; set;}
   public string PName {get; set;}
   public School schoolAttended {get; set;}
   public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

Postman request:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same in netcoreapp2.2. Works successfully.

Now when migrating from `notecoreapp2.2` to `netcoreapp3.1` I'm facing issues with `private readonly IOptions<MvcJsonOptions> _jsonOptions;`

As `MvcJsonOptions` is a breaking change from core 2.2 to 3.0.

Check this:
[Migration of netcoreapp2.2 to netcoreapp3.1 - convert MvcJsonOptions to core3.1 compatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377061/migration-of-netcoreapp2-2-to-netcoreapp3-1-convert-mvcjsonoptions-to-core3-1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).