# Getting InvalidOperationException: Incorrect Content-Type: text/plain exception when processing file through Web API Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am having an API.Net Core Web API app that has a POST method that accepts and processes a PDF file.

However, when I try to test in POSTMAN (Selecting POST, selecting Binary, choosing a file) I get a following error

> InvalidOperationException: Incorrect Content-Type: text/plain

At the following line

> var file = Request.Form.Files[0];

Please let me know if there is anything I need to fix

Thank you in advance

Here is the entire method

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("SubmitForm")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitForm()
{

    var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
    HttpClient client = GetClient();
    try
    {

        byte[] docAsBytes;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.CopyTo(ms);
            docAsBytes = ms.ToArray();
            string s = Convert.ToBase64String(docAsBytes);
            // act on the Base64 data
        }

        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(docAsBytes);
        MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
        PdfStamper outStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, m);
        string formName = outStamper.AcroFields.GetField("FormSeqNo");

        string endpointUrl = "https://myproject.sharepoint.com/sites/project" + String.Format(
           "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{0}')/Files/Add(url='{1}', overwrite=true)",
           this.Config["TemplateLibrary"].Replace(" ", "%20"),
           formName + ".pdf");

        ByteArrayContent imageBytes = new ByteArrayContent(docAsBytes);
        var result = await client.PostAsync(endpointUrl, imageBytes);

        //return result.Content.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //return ex.ToString();
    }

    return Ok(); 
}
```

Comment: My guess is you posted plain text. You need to post form data. You'll need to share your html/javascript for us to help.

Comment: I am using Postman to test the Web Api

Comment: I've never used Postman. However, this looks like it could help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request

Comment: The answer is provided in the following thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request