# Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am getting the error

```
"Resolved[org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]"
```

I tried all the options provided on previous posts it didn't work please tell me what I am doing wrong this is my first spring-boot application.

My controller

```
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

    import java.io.File;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

    @RestController
    public class SpringBootJdbcController {
        @Autowired
        JdbcTemplate jdbc;

        @Autowired
        private SpringBootJdbcService springBootJdbcService;

        @RequestMapping("/insert")
        public String index() {
            jdbc.execute("insert into user(name,email)values('javatpoint','java@javatpoint.com')");
            return "data inserted Successfully";
        }

        @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
        @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
        public void uploadFiles(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("hello hello hello");
            System.out.println("file---------" + file);
            springBootJdbcService.readConfigData(file);
        }
    }
```

My Application.properties

```
   spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
   spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=11MB
```

api call postman image :-

[image]

I don't understand what is the problem. Its my first spring-boot application please help.

Comment: your request that is uploading the file is sending it wrong

Comment: @ThomasAndolf can you suggest what could be wrong with the request and what else I can do. I tried other ways of sending my file all failed.

Comment: Please google as i said your request is probably done wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request