# Jersey: File uploading using REST API fails with HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, rest, jersey, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0

I am implementing a simple JERSEY REST API to get photos on server from the client.

My resource class looks like below:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/upload/photo")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @PubliclyAllowed
    public Response uploadPhoto(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                                @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetails) {
        System.out.println(fileDetails.getFileName());

        String uploadedFileLocation = "./" + fileDetails.getFileName();

        // save it
        writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

        String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;
        return Response.ok(output).build();
    }
```

`web.xml` looks like below

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.tarkshala</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Postman receives the following error.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: what mediatype is postman sending? I think for "binary" it sends "application/octet-stream", but your service expects "multipart/form-data". this may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/tool-for-sending-multipart-form-data-request

Comment: I checked content-type header, it was image/jpeg. I tried with multipart/form-data as well. But now it is giving  HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request error.

Comment: Thank you. The link you provided did the job for me.