# "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form." validation error, despite uploading correct file (django rest framework)

Tags: django, file-upload, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create endpoint for uploading images, in my api, which i'm building with django rest framework.
When I try to test the endpoint with postman, i'm getting response

```
"image": [
        "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
    ]
```

with status code 400.
When I try to print variable with image to console I get

```
[<TemporaryUploadedFile: test.jpg (image/jpeg)>]
```

I've checked out some tutorials and I think i'm sending the file correctly.
[That is my post man configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SugBZ.png)

that's the view

```
class ImageView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsRestaurant)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        data = {
            'image': request.data.pop('image'),
            'info': request.user.info.pk
        }
        file_serializer = RestaurantImageSerializer(data=data)

        if file_serializer.is_valid():
            file_serializer.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

the serializer

```
class RestaurantImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RestaurantImage
        fields = '__all__'
```

and model

```
class RestaurantImage(models.Model):
    info = models.ForeignKey(RestaurantInfo, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Postman configuration could be an issue, try removing all the wrong or unnecessary headers. I think you need only Authorization in your case. This also could help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41435972/4907382