# How to get path and filename from postman request body using Go

Tags: forms, go, upload, filenames

This question already asked but it is not solve my issue.

In my `Go` project am not able to print path and filename. It is showing some error like below:

`2021/10/13 16:25:07 http: panic serving [::1]:60170: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference goroutine 6 [running]:`

**My Postman collection**
[image]

**my code**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func encodeFfmpeg(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
    _, header, _ := r.FormFile("video")
    fmt.Println(header.Filename)
}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    router.HandleFunc("/encode", encodeFfmpeg).Methods("POST")

    // config port
    fmt.Printf("Starting server at 8080 \n")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
}
```

> Am trying to print filename with path **eg: /home/ramesh/videos/video.mp4**

Comment: `FormFile` returns an error. Check the error *before* touching any of the other values returned by `FormFile`. If the error is not `nil` then `header` will most likely be `nil` and the expression `header.Filename` *will* panic.

Comment: Setting `w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")` will not modify `r` in any way. It makes no sense whatsoever to have it there unless you are also responding with a payload, i.e. writing a response body, of that specific content type.

Comment: @mkopriva: I added ` _, header, err := r.FormFile("video") if err != nil { panic(err) } ` it shows this error `http: panic serving [::1]:60476: no multipart boundary param in Content-Type goroutine 6 [running]:`

Comment: That means that the `boundary` parameter in the `Content-Type` header of the Postman request is missing. This parameter is required for `multipart/form-data` to work properly. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-request-using-postman) (the boundary is mentioned at the bottom).

Comment: @mkopriva: I added the `boundary` like this `Content-Type:multipart/form-data;boundary=<calculated when request is sent>` please check this image https://ibb.co/GnhJMgj. But still showing same error

Comment: The linked answer, its associated comments, and the other answers too, suggest that you should keep Content-Type unset, and leave it to Postman to set it automatically. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA0se.png) in the second answer has the heading *"Fails If In Header"*. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08wZj.png) has the heading *"Works"*.

Comment: You are right now I removed `Content-Type` now it is working. Please add this as a answer I will give upvote and right tick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sent request is missing the `boundary` parameter in the `Content-Type` header. This parameter is required for `multipart/form-data` to work properly.

In Postman remove the explicit `Content-Type` header setting and leave it to Postman to automatically set the header with the `boundary` parameter.

For more see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16022213/965900 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/41435972/965900

Last but not least, **do not ignore errors**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it is working