# How to Solve in Swagger this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-request-using-postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, file, controller

I get this error when I add files in rest api.

```
2021-10-18 10:21:36.556  WARN 15128 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]
```

Here is my rest api.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Send file",
            notes = "This method accept a file")
    @PostMapping("/upload-file")
    public ResponseEntity<? extends Response> writeExcelledRowColumnIntoDatabase(@ApiParam(
            name = "file-name",
            type = ".xlsx",
            value = "Pass File Name",
            example = "file.xlsx",
            required = true) @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile pathFile) throws IOException {

        return this.userDetailService.acceptExcellFileAndInsertToDatabase(pathFile);

    }
```

I found something on the internet to do this, but I still get the same error. Is there any way I can solve this problem?

Comment: This should not impact the output since it's a warning not an "Error". What do you see in the swagger doc?

Comment: What exactly do you want me to say in swagger doc?

Comment: share the screenshot of the error that you are getting

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using parameter "file" in the code `@RequestParam("file")`

and the swagger doc has `file-name`

Update the function param to this:

```
 @RequestParam("file-name") MultipartFile pathFile
```