# $_FILES empty after postman upload

Tags: php, postman

I am using plain php to uplaod a file. If i try testing it with postman the FILE array is empty. I know there are a lot of similar questions out there, but I they all have either a different setup, or have some simple mistakes, but I am pretty sure I checked all common errors like php.ini values and such.
Here is my Php code and the postman request:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    echo($key . ": " . $value);
}
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value)
{
    echo($key . ": " . $value);
}
echo(count($_FILES));
```

[image]

Here are the values of my php.ini

```
file_uploads = on
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
post_max_size = 2000M
```

Does anybody have an idea what else I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have this code `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` on your page...?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send multipart/form-data request using Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015548/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-request-using-postman)

Comment: To those who wrote something about the form, read the question. 
Regarding the content type, it is already set to "multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>"

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie that actually gives me the correct output.

Comment: I think I got it. You can't echo the content of $_FILE becuase they are not a String, so it caused an error and stopped the `echo count($_FILES)`. I think the error display is set to false which is why there was no hint whats wrong.

Comment: I just choose the wrong way to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is `$_FILES` here will give you single dimensional array because you are using a single file upload, so `foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value)` will not work.

To make it work you need to send multiple files and for that, you need to make key like `barcode[]`